# Not success trying to test my catch block inside of then

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, unit-testing

I'm new on the unit testing code and lost! I'm trying throws an error for the following function to cover the catch block, but not having success and I don't know why.

Function:

```js
public initialize(): Promise<this> {
    return Promise.resolve()
      .then(() => this.getQueries())
      .catch((error: Error) => {
        this.connector.localLog.error(error, 'Failed to initialize Rest Poller Launcher:');
        throw error;
      });
  }
```

Unit test:

```js
it('should getQueries return error', () => {
  launcher.initialize()
    .then(() => {
      this.getQueries = stub().throws('TypeError');
    })
    .catch((error: Error) => {
      expect(error.message).equals('Failed to initialize Rest Poller Launcher:');
    });
});
```

Please help me

Comment: What does `getQueries` do? If it depends on some other class or resource that you can mock, just have the mock reject or throw an error.

Comment: getQueries returns a JSON.. but how to do this @p.s.w.g

Comment: If it *just* returns Json, I see no need for a catch block. Presumably it does a bit more (e.g. it calls some other method or API or depends on some other part of the app to generate the Json). You'll have to mock that process in some way, and that will depend on your mocking framework and may also depend on your testing framework. If you haven't chosen a mocking framework yet, you may need to look into that first. Personally I use [nock](https://github.com/nock/nock) for mocking REST API's, but I know Jest has its own [mock functionality](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api.html).

Comment: That's ok, I need to keep it! I just don't know how to force getQueries to return an error @p.s.w.g

Comment: Changed description, check now if makes sense what I need @p.s.w.g

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd need to stub the function before the Promise gets resolved.
Try:

```js
it('should getQueries return error', () => {
launcher.getQueries = stub().throws('TypeError');
launcher.initialize()
.then(() => {
// this should not happen
})
.catch((error: Error) => {
  expect(error.message).equals('Failed to initialize Rest Poller Launcher:');
});
```